# group by not showing all results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, group-by, distinct

So i have a table called "watches"

then i have 3 columns like so

```
id | manufacture | model
1    rolex         2483
2    rolex         3940
3    rolex         4940
4    dent          ee30
```

but i want the output to be like

```
rolex
dent
```

But when i try the following to select the manufactures

```
('SELECT manufacture FROM `watches` GROUP BY manufacture')
```

at the moments its only showing "dent" when it should be "rolex, dent". How come its not working. iv also tried this, but this gave the same result

```
('SELECT DISTINCT(`manufacture`) FROM `watches`')
```

full function

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT(`manufacture`) FROM `watches`');

$query->execute();

if($query->fetch()){

    $row = $query->fetchAll();
    foreach ($row as $i) {
        $select .= '<option value="'.$i['manufacture'].'">'.$i['manufacture'].'</option>';
    }
    return $select;
} else {
    return '<option value="0">No watches yet!</option>';
}
```

Comment: You are probably only reading the first result coming back.

Comment: iv added the full function, i dont think im reading just one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use

```
if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
```

instead of

```
if($query->fetch()){
```

because `fetch` gets the result from statement but for this you use `fetchAll` in the successing code.

Comment: Thanks, ill use this now

Comment: No problem. I'm glad could help someway.

Answer (score 0):

Add WHERE 1

```
'SELECT `manufacture` FROM `watches`WHERE 1 GROUP BY `manufacture`
```

It's good practice to always enclose the table and column names with the accent mark.

Comment: thanks, i got it too work. For some reason using the foreach loop in the class just was not working, instead i return fetchAll() and did the foreach loop on the page and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You just need to order by manufacture:

```
SELECT manufacture FROM `watches` GROUP BY manufacture ORDER BY manufacture desc
```